# How to set ArrayList values from database MySQL with IDE (Android Studio)?

Tags: java, android, mysql, arrays

I want to put data from a MySQL database table into Android Studio.
For modifying script from tutorial.

In tutorial `ArrayList` value is:

```
HomeCollection.date_collection_arr = new ArrayList<HomeCollection>();
HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection("2018-07-08" ,"Title1","Subject1","Description1"));
HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection("2018-07-09" ,"Title2","Subject2","Description2"));
HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new HomeCollection("2018-07-10" ,"Title3","Subject3","Description3"));
```

**My Question:**

How to modify data Array, in example with all data in MySql table
having below columns?

> | id | date | title | subject | description |

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: First of All what's your database SQLite or MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

//you can do like this.
get the value from arraylist into string array then split the array and then send the string to database.given below code

```
 String[] value = HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.get(0).split(",");
 String date=value[0];
 String title=value[1];
 String description=value[2];
```

//if your array list value contain space use below code

```
 String[] valuetrim= HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.get(0).split("\\s*,\\s*");
 String valuetrim=value[0];
 String valuetrim=value[1];
 String valuetrim=value[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for your clue, but I still not understand,

I try to get array list, from this way n success to views data at list (bellow array scrip),

maybe someone can give me more specific, how to implement/combine value data i have got from this way (below) to array at my question (i want to impemented sample script from this link https://www.developerbrothers.com/highlight-events-custom-calendar-android-studio-developerbrothers-com/) but i want data values get from MySql, Thanks

private void showOrder(){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList> list = new ArrayList>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(konfigurasi.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

```
        for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);

            String idplace = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_PLACE);
            String titl = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_TITLE);
            String subj = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_SUBJECT);
            String desc= jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_DESCRIPTION);
            String dateo = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_DATEORDER);

            HashMap<String,String> orders = new HashMap<>();

            orders.put(konfigurasi.TAG_PLACE,idplace);
            orders.put(konfigurasi.TAG_TITLE,titl);
            orders.put(konfigurasi.TAG_SUBJECT,subj);
            orders.put(konfigurasi.TAG_DESCRIPTION,desc);

            orders.put(konfigurasi.TAG_DATEORDER,dateo);
            list.add(orders);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            DateEventActivity.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{konfigurasi.TAG_PLACE,konfigurasi.TAG_TITLE,konfigurasi.TAG_SUBJECT,konfigurasi.TAG_DESCRIPTION,konfigurasi.TAG_DATEORDER},
            new int[]{R.id.idplace, R.id.titl, R.id.subj, R.id.desc, R.id.dateo});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void getJSON(){
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(DateEventActivity.this,"Mengambil Data","Mohon Tunggu...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            JSON_STRING = s;
            showOrder();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(konfigurasi.URL_GET_ALL);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute();
}
```